# Change page template programmatically inside foreach

Tags: page-template, php

i have been trying to attach multiple pages, eash to its page-template using a foreach loop... Manually meaning writing each page code works but inside the foreach loop it wont work.

I have several of these foreach loops so i would rather not do it manually and would also like to know / understand the issuse... here is my code

- notice that just adding a custom field with a value works.. (weird)
- what am i doing wrong?

.

```
$start_number   = 2;
$iim_pages  = array('tools', 'clients', 'users', 'resources', 'data', 'data2', 'settings');

foreach($iim_pages as $page) {

    $page_title     =   ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $page));
    $page_filename      =   'page-'.$page.'.php';

    //don't change the code bellow, unless you know what you're doing

    $page_check = get_page_by_title($page_title);
    $new_page = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'menu_order'    => $start_number,       
        'post_title'    => $page_title,
        'post_content'  => '',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
    );
    if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);

        // DOESENT WORK WITH ADD_POST_META or UPDATE_POST_META
        add_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $page_filename);  

        // THIS WORKS!
        add_post_meta($new_page_id, 'testmeta', $page_filename);  
    }

    $start_number++;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you elaborate? Do you get an error? Is the `_wp_page_template` meta value always empty or never saved? ...

Comment: hmm... great question. when clicking the fast edit on a page item i see the select as if nothing is selected - here is an image to make it more clear - http://tinypic.com/r/nvwfas/8

Comment: ps.. no error is returnd... simply put it - noting happens.

Comment: hmm, and the page templates are correct (exists)?

Comment: Yep, they exist. Also, they have a 'template name' decleration as you answered... thats a weird one. i am trying to reproduce in a different installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason for your problem.

You must remember to add the corresponding template header:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page Tools
 */
```

to your custom template files `page-tools.php`, ...

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks mate but i did remember to do that. ;( thats not the issuse...

Comment: I tested your code with `update_post_meta` and it worked for me.

Comment: Really?! ok.. going to test. (thanks for taking the time) - be right back

Comment: I tested it for the `page-tools.php` file, and I got "Tools" as the title and "Page Tools" as the page template in the *quick edit* mode. Maybe you could test it for a single page first. Did you hard delete the other pages between test runs? I guess it's just a tiny little thing that's causing the problem on your install ;-)

Comment: Ok... it does work on one page which suggests i need to debug it and its not a wordpress issuse.. thanks a lot for your time and help ;)

Comment: ok great, it sounds like you're almost there ;-) ps: I just tested it for two items, and it worked. I just had to remember to remove (hard delete) the existing pages with the same title.

Comment: you know, that might be the isuse since i used the wordpress plugin "wordpress reset" to start over again and again in order to test "on theme activation" functions... what do you mean - hard delete? do you delete the entries from the database?

Comment: What I did was to bulk trash these test pages and then I did empty the trash. You can also delete the posts permanently. Yes these pages need to be deleted from the database, for this script to work, because of the get_page_by_title() part.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help mate. going to try while monitoring the DB. have a gr8 day ;)